# In ARMv8, what happens if a global page table entry conflict across different processes?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, arm, virtual-memory, page-tables

I understand that each processes can have separate page tables and can be pointed to during context switch by updating TTBR0/1_EL1. Inside page table of each process, some entries would be process specific (nG=1) and other entries would be pointing to common resources (nG=0).

1. If a page table entry (PTE) is marked as global in one process's page-table, does it mean that the PTE has to be exactly same / pointing to exact same physical block in all other page-tables?
2. If yes, What happens in case of an inconsistency? I mean, if one process has nG = 0 and another has nG = 1 for same virtual->physical mapping, is that a faulty page-table creation from OS?
3. If my 2nd question is relevant, how does OS make sure that every global PTE is coherent across different processes, so that one update on Global PTE is seen by all processes' page-tables?

I searched in stack-overflow and other sites, but couldn't get a satisfactory explanation regarding Global page maintenance.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is some process with one or more threads. OS creates single virtual-to-physical translation for this process (page table). When any thread of this process is on any CPU, PT registers of the CPU are set to point to the process page table. So it is how OS make PTEs of process coherent, by using single copy of page table from all CPUs. And the real problem is PTE caching in TLB - when one of PTEs in memory is changed, TLB of other CPUs running threads of this process (or having PTE cached in their TLB) should be updated `flush_tlb_*`: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cachetlb.txt

Comment: I understand about TLB invalidation to another core when one core updates pagetable of SAME process. I'm confused about the global pages which would need to be same (or atleast that's what I think) for different processes. If one process updates a global PTE, does the update need to be propagated to other processes' page-tables? How is this done?

Comment: Is it about Linux, which version? Can you link some ARM docs with nG bit description? In x86/x86_64 world "global" part of page table ("negative addresses" is we interpret pointer as signed) is used for kernel memory, and it is often mapped using larger pages (2M, 1G) statically at boot and don't change. Other (theoretical) way is to use single page table subtree for kernel space and just link into it from all process page tables (it will still require tlb flush when some kernel mappings are changed). Earlier ttbr1 was used for kernel http://elinux.org/Tims_Notes_on_ARM_memory_allocation

Comment: I was not asking about any specific OS; just wanted to know an example of how global pages are maintained. Here is a link describing nG bit : https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/b/DDI0487B_a_armv8_arm.pdf . Check on page D4-2116

Comment: In linux 4.11 it (nG=1) is used in EFI mapping and nG=1 for all normal mappings: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/ident/PTE_NG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. If a page table entry (PTE) is marked as global in one process's page-table, does it mean that the PTE has to be exactly same / pointing to exact same physical block in all other page-tables?

If PTE has nG=0 (set as global) in some page-table (in memory) it means nothing. But when this PTE is loaded into TLB cache, this bit changes how TLB matches this virtual address against this cached PTE (in modes when ASIDs are supported; "*To resolve this problem, ARMv8 also adds a nonGlobal (nG) flag in a page table descriptor, thereby ASID is ignored on specific pages by clearing the flag*" - https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3062267 "Instruction-Level Data Isolation for the Kernel on ARM"): every request is matched from current ASID to the PTE ASID for nG=1 (process) mappings, and will match based only on virtual address for nG=0 (global) mappings. So, it is very convenient to keep global mappings the same in all page tables. And use they only for something global, like kernel address-space, without frequent changes.

> 2. What happens in case of an inconsistency? I mean, if one process has nG = 0 and another has nG = 1 for same virtual->physical mapping, is that a faulty page-table creation from OS?

Nothing happens when incorrect PTE is in memory. When it is cached in TLB and process is switched, wrong physical address will be generated for access to this virtual address (mapping).

> how does OS make sure that every global PTE is coherent across different processes, so that one update on Global PTE is seen by all processes' page-tables?

When OS creates some mapping, it edits relevant page tables. So, when global mapping is added, it will write it to the correct place. I think (but no sure) it can be possible to partially share some subtrees of kernel-space pagetables between processes (when architecture implements page tables as hierarchical trees like in x86). There is often kernel space - user space split (historically 2GB/2GB of virtual address space https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/1/10/189), and half of virtual memory is mapped for kernel (globally). On ARM this split is usually static using EL1's TTBR0 for user-space page table root and TTBR1 for kernel-space page table root (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/BABBEFAE.html with Translation Control Register TCR_EL1 used to find the split point). With L2/L3 page tables ARM will have subtrees in page tables too, so some L2 records of different processes may point to the same L3 page table for part of kernel/global mappings (check Figure 12.8 Virtual to Physical Address translation for a 64KB page in http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch12s03.html ARM Cortex-A Series Programmer’s Guide for ARMv8-A - 12.3. Translating a Virtual Address to a Physical Address). Another possible solution of managing global mappings in different processes is to have links from OS memory descriptor (VMA in Linux) to all page tables where it was registered, and do updates with some kind of stop all cpus/cores/processes which can use it, change the mapping, do tlb flush for range on every CPU core, unstop all cpus/cores/processes.

As I understand, Linux kernel 4.11 for ARM64 knows about NG bit as **`PTE_NG`** [`arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable-hwdef.h`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable-hwdef.h#L162):

```
 #define PTE_NG         (_AT(pteval_t, 1) << 11)    /* nG */
```

but [just uses it](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/ident/PTE_NG) by setting it to nG=1 (process) everywhere for user-space and nG=0 (global) for kernel-space (`PROT_DEVICE_*`, `PROT_NORMAL_*`, `PROT_KERNEL_*`):
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable-prot.h#L67

```
#define PAGE_KERNEL     __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_PXN | PTE_UXN | PTE_DIRTY | PTE_WRITE)
#define PAGE_KERNEL_RO      __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_PXN | PTE_UXN | PTE_DIRTY | PTE_RDONLY)
#define PAGE_KERNEL_ROX     __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_UXN | PTE_DIRTY | PTE_RDONLY)
#define PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC    __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_UXN | PTE_DIRTY | PTE_WRITE)
#define PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC_CONT   __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_UXN | PTE_DIRTY | PTE_WRITE | PTE_CONT)
...
#define PAGE_NONE       __pgprot(((_PAGE_DEFAULT) & ~PTE_VALID) | PTE_PROT_NONE | PTE_PXN | PTE_UXN)
#define PAGE_SHARED     __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_USER | PTE_NG | PTE_PXN | PTE_UXN | PTE_WRITE)
#define PAGE_SHARED_EXEC    __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_USER | PTE_NG | PTE_PXN | PTE_WRITE)
#define PAGE_COPY       __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_USER | PTE_NG | PTE_PXN | PTE_UXN)
#define PAGE_COPY_EXEC      __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_USER | PTE_NG | PTE_PXN)
#define PAGE_READONLY       __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_USER | PTE_NG | PTE_PXN | PTE_UXN)
#define PAGE_READONLY_EXEC  __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_USER | PTE_NG | PTE_PXN)
#define PAGE_EXECONLY       __pgprot(_PAGE_DEFAULT | PTE_NG | PTE_PXN)
```

And documentation of Linux/Aarch64 says only about TTBR0/TTBR1: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm64/memory.txt "Memory Layout on AArch64 Linux"

> User addresses have bits 63:48 set to 0 while the kernel addresses have
>   the same bits set to 1. TTBRx selection is given by bit 63 of the
>   virtual address. The swapper_pg_dir contains only kernel (global)
>   mappings while the user pgd contains only user (non-global) mappings.
>   The swapper_pg_dir address is written to TTBR1 and never written to
>   TTBR0.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So there is indeed a requirement to keep all global page table entries same for different process page-tables

Comment: There is no hard requirement in ARM Architecture to do it, it just most convenient  way of managing it. We may imagine some cases when there will be several global mapping, if we have two sets of processes and will never map them into the same set of CPU cores. Apparently Linux uses global only for TTBR1 and always uses same half-tree of page tables on TTBR1s of all cores.